# Table View in a content View controller of a popover not resizing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopover

Background: I have a View controller which has a header view`(UIView)`, a footer view `(UIView)`, table view and a search bar`(UISearchBar)` above it . This is made using xib. I need to present this inside a popover. This is done and everything is working fine.

Problem: The problem begins when i launch the key pad for search. The key board shrinks the size of the popover. Because of this i cannot see the bottom cells of my table. I have no idea why. My guess is its not getting resized properly.

What i tried:  I tried to reduce the height of the table using keyboard notifications. It works but i want a more elegant solution and also want to what i am doing wrong ?

This is specific to iOS 6.0. It works fine with 7.0

**EDIT**
On further testing i found out that my solution is not working :(

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

View controller xib schema:
[image]

Comment: Are you using constraints? Have you tried setting controller.view.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight and tableView.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight and making your header and footer views the header and footer of the tableView?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen: Yup... the autoresizing masks are set in the xib. I forgot to mention.. no i am not using constraints.

Comment: In your question, when you say "above it" you mean as subviews of its view right? Do you have a standard UITableView, or a subclass? Is autoresizing definitely set on all views in the hierarchy? Could you paste some of your code/a screenshot of IB?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen: Hi george. i did verify that my autoresizing masks are set for all views. I cannot upload the screen shot since it has been designed with specific wireframes. However i will attach a schema of the xib to help in understanding. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you verify that viewWillLayoutSubviews is being called on your controller?

Comment: yup it is being called ..

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, I'll have a proper look when I get home later!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the desired size of your view controller within the popover. 
This is done in two ways: You can override the method `contentSizeForViewInPopover` on the view controller that you are displaying within a popover, like so:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover
{
    // return the size WITHOUT a navigationbar height
    return CGSizeMake(320, 300);
}
```

And/or you can set a property on the popover, like so:

```
// if your inner viewcontroller is a UINavigationViewController, return the size WITH the   
// navbar height
self.popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 344);
```

Notice the comments.

Comment: i am setting the contentSizeForViewInPopover in viewdidload of the viewcontroller :(

Comment: @PrathameshSaraf I think that's too late. Try overriding the method and see if that works.